# Webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin - Bundled file serves up HTML?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am using webpack with HtmlWebpackPlugin. Serving up the generated index.html with a Flask server. The index.html is called fine from the Flask server. However, I think there is an error in my webpack config that is making the app.bundle.js go bad.

On the browser developer tools I can see the error is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

When the browser loads the app.bundle.js, it seems to think it is a copy of the index.html. However on my local computer I can see that the app.bundle.js is the webpack Javascript bundle.

Webpack Config File

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static/dist"),
    filename: '[name].bundle.[hash].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.template.ejs'),
      showErrors: true,
      hash: true,
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: { importLoaders: 1, modules: true },
          },
          "sass-loader"
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
      }
    ],

  },
  resolve: {
    alias:{
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, './components'),
      containers: path.resolve(__dirname, './containers'),
      channels: path.resolve(__dirname, './channels'),
      models: path.resolve(__dirname, './models'),
      stores: path.resolve(__dirname, './stores'),
      lib: path.resolve(__dirname, './lib')
    },
    modules: ['components', "node_modules"],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

[image: HTML in bundled Javascript Source]

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by not loading in the JS source properly. It was two levels below where the actual main.bundle.[hash].js source was.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.[hash].js"></script>
```

Should have been

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/dist/main.bundle.[hash].js"></script>
```

However the real problem was the browser's fallback. It was not able to find the source correctly, and dug up the HTMl file that required the failed script include. It ended up reading a JS file when it pulled up HTML.

I fixed this by adding a publicPath to my webpack config.

```
module.exports = {
...
  output: {
      ...
      publicPath: 'static/dist'
      ...
  }
...
}
```